# Can't output array correctly

Tags: php, arrays

I want to have output of array `$mass` like this

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,"e","f"
```

using three "for" loops but something is wrong in the code and I have output like this

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 e f
```

Any ideas ?

```
$mass=array($a=array($b=array(0,1,2,3,4,5),6,7,8,9,10),11,12,"e","f");

for($i=0;$i<count($mass);$i++){
    for($y=0;$y<count($mass[$i]);$y++){
        for($z=0;$z<count($mass[$i][$y]);$z++){
            echo $mass[$i][$y][$z];
            echo "</br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your loops expect a different array structure. Where does your original `$mass` data come from? What does it represent? Are you able to change the structure of the array?

Comment: @showdev I guess this was the way the homework question was set

Comment: actually its not homework ,its my idea to create such mass... With what loop can i output data from this array 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,"e","f"

Comment: My original $mass data is my imagination ,i just created an array.It doesn't represent anything just data that i want to output.I am able to change the structure but i dont want to do it because i want a loop that would output the data from this array with this structure.How to output it ?

Comment: Why does it have to use `for` loops

Comment: Just guessing how to output it using "for " loop .

Answer (score 0):

Using a little bit of recursion it can be done quite simply like this

```
<?php
$mass=array(array(array(0,1,2,3,4,5),6,7,8,9,10),11,12,"e","f");

function pr_all($arr)
{
    $out = '';
    foreach ( $arr as $a ) {
        if ( is_array($a) ) {
            $out .= pr_all($a);
        } else {
            $out .= $a . '<br>';
        }
    }
    return $out;
}

echo pr_all($mass);
```

Results:

```
0<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>11<br>12<br>e<br>f<br>
```